# PHP show 'include' wherever i want on a page

Tags: php

How can i echo the content of included file on a specific place on a page if the file being included in the beginning of the page?

plugin.php:

```
 <?php $txt = 'HELLO WORLD';?>
  <div id="pl"> 
     ... some stuff.. <?php echo $text; ?>
  </div>
```

main.php:

```
 <?php
 include 'plugin.php';
 ?>

 <body>
  <div>SOME TEXT BEFORE THE OUTPUT...</div>
  <div><?php //content of included file goes here  ?></div>
 </body>
```

Comment: try `echo $text` there

Comment: `Include` where you want the content outputted.

Comment: Do you want just $txt or the full thing?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
   $text = include 'plugin.php';
?>

<body>
    <div>SOME TEXT BEFORE THE OUTPUT...</div>
    <div><?php echo $text;//content of included file goes here  ?></div>
</body>
```

You can store the context of included file in a variable. Try this for example.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work as it should in my code.. but thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do

```
 <body>
  <div>SOME TEXT BEFORE THE OUTPUT...</div>
  <div><?php  include 'plugin.php';  ?></div>
 </body>
```

hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ob_start();
include($path);
return ob_get_clean();
```

This is what helped.